# How to validate a <textarea></textarea> with Jquery if no form exists?

Tags: jquery, validation

I knew there is a JQuery form validation, but if there is no form, how to validate with Jquery? Say, there is a

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

, I want to send the text via AJAX instead of form. How to validate before sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<textarea>` tag is not allowed outside a `<form>`. What you're proposing wouldn't pass an HTML validator. Just surround your `<textarea>` with a `<form>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just validate it yourself.  If there is certain requirements that you want to check, before the submission, or attach an onblur event to the `textarea` and you can ensure that the data is correct.

I would opt for the onblur event as that would enable you to let the user know quickly if there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

just pulling the textarea by it id

i.e.

```
$('#mytextarea').value();
```

Answer (score 1):

So you check the value before you send through AJAX.

```
$('input#mybutton').click(function() {
    var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val();
    // Validate the text HERE
    $.ajax({
        type:     "GET",
        url:      pURL,
        async:    false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(pReturn) {
            // Process the return.
        }
    });
});
```